# How to get the latest Data with WHERE and MAX in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is my current MySQL Table:

```
Crop             ID  Price  DateUpdated             Area
Okra             4   50     2014-02-05 21:42:26     Bulua
Eggplant         5   20     2014-02-05 21:42:26     Lapasan
Okra             6   35     2014-02-05 21:42:26     Agora
Cauliflower      8   300    2014-02-05 21:42:26     Patag
Onion            9   10     2014-02-05 22:02:34     Cogon
Kalabasa         10  50     2014-02-05 22:59:30     Cogon
Garlic           11  130    2014-02-05 22:59:44     Cogon
Onion            14  34.4   2014-02-05 23:12:21     Cogon
Onion            15  54     2014-02-07 02:40:13     Cogon
```

I want to query all `'Crops'` with their `'Price'` as latest in the area name `'Cogon'`. 
This is the last query that I used:

```
SELECT ID, Crop, Area, MAX( DateUpdated ) 
AS Latest, DateUpdated, Price 
FROM crops 
WHERE Area = TRIM( 'Cogon' ) 
GROUP BY Area, Crop;
```

In which I want to get all crops in 'Cogon' with their latest prices.

Well the syntax above outputs all the crops in 'Cogon'. However, it does not output the latest Price of Onion (ID 14) but instead outputs the older data (ID 9).

Comment: This question is asked, and correctly answered, every single day - but that's not to say that every answer is correct.

Comment: @Strawberry On a logical standpoint it should've printed my desired output but fails. Can you please explain which part makes a mess from it?

Comment: I can't be bothered. That exact question is answered all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you say like

```
SELECT Crop, 
Area, 
DateUpdated, 
Price 
FROM crops cr
WHERE trim(Area) = 'Cogon' 
and
DateUpdated = (select max(DateUpdated) 
               from crops 
               where Crop = cr.Crop and trim(Area) = 'Cogon' ) ;
```

Comment: The code that you gave me work. Sir, if you have time can you please explain the part after `FROM`?

Comment: The `where Crop = cr.Crop` needs to be: `where Crop = cr.Crop AND trim(Area) = 'Cogon'`

Comment: Sure; the correlated subquery part `DateUpdated = (select ....)` is getting the latest date of crops as in outer query. i.e, if in outer query crop is Onion then it finds latest date for Onion and gives you the result accordingly.

Comment: @ypercube, make sense since OP is cocentrating on 'Cogon' Area. changed it. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: I removed the unnecessary `GROUP BY`

Answer (score -2):

You want to `ORDER BY DateUpdated DESC` or `ORDER BY ID DESC`

Comment: I already tried the `ORDER BY DateUpdated DESC` but it still outputs the older one which is `ID 9` of Onion

also, the `ORDER BY ID DESC` would output the same thing.

Comment: Try reversing the order, so `ORDER BY DateUpdated ASC` or `ORDER BY ID ASC`. I would have sworn that desc order would have given you the correct results, but the opposite order should give you the correct one.